# User input on Google map V2 marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I was wondering is it possible to allow the user name or add information to a marker which is placed on a long click of the map currently i have the marker title set to "Marker":

```
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(point)
                .title("Marker")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    }
```

I want the user to be able to add info such as place name etc. rather then pre setting the title as "marker"?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but here goes. 
I had the same problem, and i just used a dialog box for input

```
// Init the dialog object
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Enter description");

// Set up the input
final EditText input = new EditText(this);

// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
builder.setView(input);

// Set up the buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        String description;
        description = input.getText().toString();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(newPoint)
            .title(description)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new         DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

builder.show();
```

You could also read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows) about infowindows.

Hope it helps!